# "Number of query values and destination fields are not the same." in Automation Anywhere

Tags: ms-access, automation, insert, rpa, automationanywhere

I'm trying to do a use case for Automation Anywhere, and i have an excel file with 11 columns (first name, last name, age, phone... etc and medical diagnosis) and on my database, i have tables based on the name of the medical diagnosis ready, so for example if a person has ***hypertension***, then it will move his/her information into the table based on the diagnosis, if the person has another diagnosis, then it will insert that person's information into the other table and so on, I have assigned every column to one variable as well, and what i did till now is as follows (if pic not working, you can try and see from this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaYGF.jpg)

[image: AutomationAnywhere]

So in my database, i have the exact same names as the columns in the excel sheet (except for the medical diagnosis column, because the tables have the name of the diagnosis)
Whenever i try to run just to test if the data would get exported to the Database, i would get this error "Number of query values and destination fields are not the same." and this is the SQL command that i've used:

```
INSERT INTO $vDiagnosis$ VALUES ('$vID$','$vFirstName$', 
'$vLastName$','$vGender$','$vPhone$','$vAge$','$vDateOfVisit$',
'$vCondition$','$vInsuranceCo$','$vInsuranceNr$')
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: If you are passing field names in variables then need to use `SELECT … FROM tablename` instead of VALUES(). If you are passing a value and not a field name then need field names in the INTO clause.

Comment: Read about SQL INSERT INTO. If you don't supply **all** columns in `VALUE` clause, you must list the columns you want to insert into.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], then improve (edit) question! E.g. don't show images of text, copy and paste the text!

Comment: @June7 sure it doesnÄt fail because it uses parameters (from workshee)t, but you can't use a parameter for destination table?  OP even if possible don't do that! Read on databae normalization, ten rethink the process!

Comment: @June7 I'm passing the value of every field in each row, except for column 8, into the tables of the database, and I used `INSERT INTO "table-name" VALUES( )`, and the column have the same name as in each table

Comment: Seems comments still apply. Compiled SQL has data in VALUES clause pulled in via column variables. Pulling values from cells of specified columns. Need to specify destination fields. Never encountered Automation Anywhere before but using it doesn't change SQL structure and syntax.

Comment: Okay, just tested. If you are sending values to every field in table, including autonumber if there is one, then specifying fields not needed but data must be same order as fields in table design. Agree with @ComputerVersteher that you need to reconsider database schema. If diagnosis tables all have same fields, then should be 1 table with another field for diagnosis category.

Comment: Also, repeating info in table is bad design. If a patient can have multiple diagnosis records, then patient info should not be repeated. Patient info should be in Patients table and Diagnoses table should have a foreign key field for PatientID - not name, age, phone, etc.

Comment: @June7 thanks for all of your help man! and sorry for the late response... Anyway I don't know what was going with the Automation Anywhere Client, but I tried the same `INSERT INTO` statement that i had before and it worked just fine... And I'm not really familiar with SQL itself, neither MS-Access, but i know the basics.

Comment: @June7 I was also trying not to repeat the info in the diagnosis tables, so I added a field called "VisitingNr" which will increment every time a person visits, but here i started facing problems, because of the primary key i guess, so i set a DBID (AutoNumber) but here the problem that i faced is that when it faces another repeated ID it would go and try to create another diagnosis table with the same name and then fails because the table already exists.

Comment: @June7 True, i was thinking of what you said earlier about not repeating information, but in this case, I was thinking of creating tables for each diagnosis, plus a table for all patients, and in the diagnosis tables, i would have the Patients ID, Date of Visit, VisitingNr and the Condition of the patient, and in the patients table, all of the other information including the Patient's ID. What do you think about this? Or you think there is a better design?

Comment: As already noted, if diagnosis tables all have same fields, should be one table with another field for diagnosis category/code.